# Proving an identity involving $\int_{1}^{\infty} u^{s} e^{-u p} d u$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

In [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1909.06941.pdf) paper the author (Mario DeFranco) mentions the following formula

$$
\int_{1}^{\infty} u^{s} e^{-u p} d u=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(2^{n}\right)^{s+1} e^{-2^{n} p} \int_{0}^{1}(1+u)^{s} e^{-2^{n} u p} d u
$$

but no explicit reference was given or I could not find it nor a demonstration of it. So I'm looking for references or a demonstration of it as an answer of to this question.

Thanks.

Comment: This looks like a Laplace transform, if you set $u = v + 1$. Does that let you arrive at the formula?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\int_1^\infty u^s e^{-up}\,du=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\int_{2^n}^{2^{n+1}}u^s e^{-up}\,du\underset{[u=2^n(1+v)]}{\phantom{\Big[}=\phantom{\Big]}}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}2^{n(s+1)}e^{-2^n p}\int_0^1(1+v)^s e^{-2^n vp}\,dv.$$